# Non-symmetric Braiding on finite group Representation Categories

Tags: braided-tensor-categories

Do the fusion categories $Rep(S_4)$ and $Rep(A_5)$ admit non-symmetric braidings?  All the other rep. cats. of finite subgroups of $SU(2)$ do (in the McKay correspondence).  My guess is no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eric,

The answer is no for $Rep(A_5)$ and yes for $Rep(S_4)$,
thanks to Victor Ostrik's observation.
For a braided category $C$ let $C'$ denote its Mueger center,
i.e., the subcategory of objects $Y$ in $C$ such
that the square of braiding of $Y$ with any $X$ in $C$ is identity.
So $C$ is symmetric if $C=C'$ and $C$ is non-degenerate (or modular)
if $C'$ is trivial.

Note that $C:=Rep(A_5)$ is simple, i.e., it has no non-trivial
proper fusion subcategories.  Now if $C$ has a non-symmetric braiding
then $C' \neq C$ is a proper subcategory. So $C'$ is trivial, i.e.,
$C$ with the above braiding is non-degenerate (modular). This cannot 
happen (e.g., $C$ has a simple object  of dimension 5, but in
a modular category the square of dimension of any object divides
dimension of the category, thanks to the result of Etingof-Gelaki).

For $D:= Rep(S_4)$ there is a non-symmetric braiding with $D'=Rep(S_3)$,
namely the equivariantization of a pointed category $Vec_{Z/2Z\oplus Z/2Z}$
with respect to an action of $S_3$.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri!  How do you rule out $D^\prime=Rep(S_3)$?

Comment: Dmitri, for $D=Rep(S_4)$ there is one more possibility, namely
$D'=Rep(S_3)$. Actually I believe that for $D=Rep(S_4)$ the alternative braiding is possible. Namely consider pointed category
with underlying group $Z/2Z \oplus Z/2Z$ and quadratic form which takes value -1 on a nontrivial element. Then equivariantize with 
respect to the obvious $S_3-$action.

Comment: Victor is right. I will edit the above answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can also answer the question using the classification of R-matrices over group algebras. Indeed, the R-matrices in the Hopf algebra $ kG $, are classified by pairs $ (A, \rho) $ where $ A \subset G $ is an abelian normal subgroup and $ \rho: A \times A \to k^* $ is a bilinear form ad $ G $-invariant. It is easy to see that the associated R-matrix is symmetric if and only if the bilinear form is skew-symmetric.

It is now clear that $ kA_5 $ does not have R-matrices in addition to the trivial. On the other hand, the only normal abelian subgroup of $ S_4 $ is formed by the union of the conjugacy classes of $(12)(34)$ and the identity of $S_4$. This normal subgroup is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2 $. As was mentioned by Ostrik, one example could be the next: the quadratic form that takes values -1 on nontrivial elements. That bilinear form satisfies the conditions and defines a non-symmetric R-matrix.

Comment: Thanks Cesar.  What is a reference for this classification?  Is there a variation for twisted group algebras?  So this might lead to a more general statement for categories with the same fusion rules as $Rep(G)$ for $G$ a non-abelian simple group?

Comment: 1) You can see the result in Example 2.1 of arXiv: math/0605731, or arXiv: q-alg/9706007.


2) On the variation for the twisted group algebras, I do not know anything, but I do not know which would be a possible variation.


3) The result implies that the only braid on Rep (G) for G a non-abelian simple group is the trivial braid. But I think you can not say anything specific for fusion categories with the same  fusion rules of Rep(G), since there are pairs of fusion categories  with the same rules of fusion, where one of them is braided and the other has not a braid. 


Comment: Cesar, I was thinking of using Prop. 9.11 of 0809.3031 to say something about when the only braidings on a category are symmetric.  Thanks for the references.