# Easy example of a non-symmetric braiding of $\operatorname{Rep}(G)$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, hopf-algebras, braided-tensor-categories

What is the smallest group $G$ such that $\operatorname{Rep}(G)$ has a non-symmetric braiding (or just an easy example)?

I seem to remember a result classifying all universal $R$-matrices of $\mathbb C[G]$ for finite groups $G$, but cannot find this. But I remember that with this result, I found that the only non-trivial universal $R$-matrix of $C_2$ was

$$R=\frac12(e\otimes e+e\otimes g+g\otimes e-g\otimes g).$$

But this $R$-matrix gives a symmetric braiding on $\operatorname{Rep}(C_2)$. I'm looking for one that will give me a non-symmetric braiding.

Comment: Obvious comment: Rep(C_2) has a non-symmetric braiding giving (a category equivalent to) super vector spaces. I guess you are after something more sophisticated?

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson By a braiding $c$ being symmetric, I mean that $c_{W,V}\circ c_{V,W}=\operatorname{id}_{V\otimes W}$. This is the case for the braiding on the category of super vector spaces that you mentioned, and it is in fact the braiding corresponding to the universal $R$-matrix that I mention in my question.

Comment: You might want to look at the answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26268/.

Comment: @shinchan: of course you're right. Sorry for silly comment. Please ignore.

Comment: What is meant by "smallest"? is $G$ meant to be a finite group?

Answer (score 5):

Since you mention classification results for $R$-matrices:
For finite abelian groups, there is a bijection between the set of universal $R$-matrices of the group hopf algebra $\mathbb C[G]$, the set of bicharacters $\theta: G\times G\rightarrow\mathbb C^*$ on the group $G$ and the set of the braidings of the monoidal Category of representations of the group hopf algebra $\mathbb C[G]$. (If I remember correctly, this was first obtained by Scheunert at
[Universal R-matrices for finite Abelian groups - a new look at graded multilinear algebra](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9508016)).
This bijection is such that the skew-symmetric bicharacters correspond to triangular  $R$-matrices and to symmetric braidings.

So, if you are looking for non-symmetric braidings this is equivalent to looking for   non-triangular $R$-matrices or for non skew-symmetric bicharacters on the group. In this sense, an "easy" example can be obtained if you take a [symmetric bicharacter](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869300X00580/1-s2.0-S0021869398975585/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIHMs7JFN%2Bprpgdh%2BhhG2f%2BRnGAipFmKHyim4BzRu1usOAiEAgyRfJbr0iwqWXZjOk62Riae7oCFBvmnBo4Hfclg4cFEqswUITxAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDClOYVAxrRj4kXKAaCqQBfF87nRklLW%2BIsQ4iCjWjm3L9NL5A%2BshS2NYCkRmAR2pKbwcQjPyaFXM2YaP0yO02elUc%2FtiBNx040XRK4m4x%2FK8e%2FR0%2BSyTJRsIDBGQPWPDqMbJNciApI54BmeYKS8cr1ReTnuopqZoHONfcRrgx73jtXy6YML06vTWDaoyZVS%2BzujnOE6ZowzBFB6Ws9aQblHCfMC2deXfmbZE243XW3ItWisJ6BSw5v4qdEWWZjynJfbUXjGDPbLc7yQEzMKpnxKnyCz01a%2BicZGPf87sf5D5W6UWbF9pwIGFYQwx72leBn9tmg6fQN6hYHGOhCAwWIpe9v3tWNFUzWZEAdFbCcx0R69xQH88LdOoEL3wFH1b26fowpX%2FOiKeewbiDEEZhKLGmjSbJe%2BgzwN9nql7U%2Fom03GuMC5mEILAmiSxduSwPAnl%2Fkpv%2BXuf5YOyb4cGb3tPomeDjIowcVTZvdA4pSbED94wGgfcNPTmzzk9lChM8Iip0BliiBcDJZz8zDVjnTSlqBA2wtLzf4C1ES1rAY7VPrQwsRLu8jBHQ1BhtFBLBOw8NEh598ZhxlUzSmI4BY1%2FVQvz363ihbrZBe2UjGvz468otvZFqnaf63%2FGeUNS933aPP6vBS4bj5Mh08L4keNR6MvpOYQXuF0HwNdD%2BhscRKAd%2F9xt72vRHmq4GK2%2BZDvnEpcll%2FXzRHemzi5SYhQXOmz7A%2B3AlOCzrmXKgHmyRJ5hgbMQMENkpIaiyLEr1T18Jr4VWyuokmI9zn1mxG8r9O48T6cN6cOzSBPP8CBqvYFCPRK7Jf5u62uqQV29VDr8sMoAx2kKZmdoeBXdK6MUNscLkCErTSCjXwnolZsMLNpvqCKSas6h6Mv%2BF5l%2BMIWPu6YGOrEBWkimo0jk8f3f86dunUWT8bHtFk8D%2BfFA8b%2FL7GhHUbuXayyWIa2UApYOVO8f67ogdMtMIlF0u1xloq52cP0hq3MYJoDK1hMy7A2%2FbOzZyCeTps4KfimWc9FBnEvPoyEl95ybwcUBR2tmWRxIC6FonZt2equeMXV3orWOG9IMPStw%2BgIOpCTP0ZosxEfk8NqmTZswhv7WLCSaoe8RMcMAjsvkI40Zf3Or4XVpT%2FcUIUOx&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230805T225956Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYYS7JA6UO%2F20230805%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1297e8a6897f27b932a9124065923467246e739d80b5361f0ba2fef138bb4e8c&hash=caeb27e9c5dbebecdaef6d5509dfd930d421c8d88974990127cd9ab69c7a650e&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021869398975585&tid=spdf-19a472cb-e23d-4aad-8d30-e0a9d379da6f&sid=046206d783e0414ec4693c6655eeeaf06d83gxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=02155807535507555055&rr=7f22a744898238d5&cc=gr) of the Klein 4-group $\mathbb Z_2 \oplus\mathbb Z_2$. Plugging this into the formulae given in Sceunert's paper you can obtain (with straightforward computations) the corresponding non-triangular $R$-matrix and the corresponding non-symmetric braiding for the category of the reps of the group hopf algebra.

Comment: For my own sake, I'll try to explicitly write down the above. The non-symmetric $R$-matrix on $G=\mathbf{Z}/2\times\mathbf{Z}/2$ sends $R(a,b)=(-1)^{a_2\cdot b_1}$ where $a=(a_1,a_2)$. This satisfies the Yang-Baxter equation because $R(a+a',b)=R(a,b)R(a',b)$ and likewise for $b+b'$, and almost cocommutativity is automatic because $\mathbf{C}[G]$ is co/commutative. Similarly, given a symmetric $R$-matrix on any $G$, we get a non-symmetric $R$-matrix on $G^2$. I guess this also works for any symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$, that $\mathcal{C}\otimes \mathcal{C}$ has a braided structure.